# How to write JavaScript function that will properly indent scheme code?

Tags: javascript, scheme, lisp

I have scheme in JavaScript (called [LIPS](https://jcubic.github.io/lips/)) and I'm writing multiline interpreter using jQuery Terminal and newly created example for multline command, the code simple prevent default behavior of enter key.

The issue with my lisp is that it don't look nice without auto indentation on enter, like in GNU Emacs. So I've written simple auto indentation, but I don't know how to make it work the same as in GNU Emacs. I was looking and source code for [lisp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/da0054c30729e58259c1e7251cb03c8ef13ff943/lisp/emacs-lisp/lisp-mode.el) but I'm not emacs lisp expert, and the code give me no clue what is the proper logic for indentation.

Here is my starting code:

```js
// lisp indentation function
function indent(term, level, offset) {
    // offset is for prompt on first line
    // level if for single indent of next line

    // function return code before cursor
    // to the beginning of the command
    var code = term.before_cursor(); 
    var lines = code.split('\n');
    var prev_line = lines[lines.length - 1];
    var parse = prev_line.match(/^(\s*)(.*)/);
    var spaces = parse[1].length || offset;
    var re_if = /(.*\(if\s+)\(/;
    var m = prev_line.match(re_if);
    if (m) {
        spaces = m[1].length;
    } else if (parse[2].match(/\(/)) {
        spaces += level;
    }
    return spaces;
}
var term = $(selector).terminal(function(code, term) {
    lips.exec(code, env).then(function(ret) {
        ret.forEach(function(ret) {
            if (ret !== undefined) {
                env.get('print').call(env, ret);
            }
        });
    }).catch(function(e) {
        term.error(e.message);
    });
}, {
    name: 'lisp',
    prompt: 'lips> ',
    enabled: false,
    greetings: false,
    keymap: {
        ENTER: function(e, original) {
            if (lips.balanced_parenthesis(this.get_command())) {
                original();
            } else {
                var i = indent(this, 3, this.get_prompt().length);
                this.insert('\n' + (new Array(i + 1).join(' ')));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/LQBaaV) it have keypress and keydown that you can ignore, important is `keymap.ENTER` and `indent` function.

My question is how I should go about and implement scheme indentation? What are the rules? I think that I will be able to make it work if I know the algorithm, but there are probably lot of edge cases, how indent should work.

My base code only indent 2 spaces for each newline and align to first parenthesis after `if` but only first line because it only check previous line.

The helper function that cane be used is `tokenize(code: string, extended: boolean)` that return array of strings or object with `{token, offset}` (offset is index of the token inside the string).

**UPDATE**:

Here is my updated code, the only special is `if` it now works with multiline.

```js
   // return S-Expression that's at the end (the one you're in)
   function sexp(tokens) {
       var count = 1;
       var i = tokens.length;
       while (count > 0) {
           token = tokens[--i];
           if (!token) {
               return;
           }
           if (token.token === '(') {
               count--;
           } else if (token.token == ')') {
               count++;
           }
       }
       return tokens.slice(i);
   }
   // basic indent
   function indent(term, level, offset) {
       var code = term.before_cursor();
       var tokens = lips.tokenize(code, true);
       var last_sexpr = sexp(tokens);
       var lines = code.split('\n');
       var prev_line = lines[lines.length - 1];
       var parse = prev_line.match(/^(\s*)/);
       var spaces = parse[1].length || offset;
       if (last_sexpr) {
           if (last_sexpr[0].line > 0) {
               offset = 0;
           }
           if (['define', 'begin'].indexOf(last_sexpr[1].token) !== -1) {
               return offset + last_sexpr[0].col + level;
           } else {
               // ignore first 2 tokens - (fn
               var next_tokens = last_sexpr.slice(2);
               for (var i in next_tokens) {
                   var token = next_tokens[i];
                   if (token.token.trim()) {
                       // indent of first non space after function
                       return token.col;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return spaces + level;
   }
```

the code can be tested here: https://jcubic.github.io/lips/ did I miss some edge case, or is `if` the only special indentation case?

Comment: I think this is not too broad, because lips syntax (especially scheme) is very simple so thre should not be many cases only list of forms (only few) and indent level for next line.

Comment: I am mostly curious about why that function is not written in LIPS itself; but apart from that, you could also have a look at https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/master/contrib/slime-cl-indent.el#L683 for how you can have a DSL for describing indentation levels, etc. For rules, see maybe http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style

Comment: @coredump thanks that second is link, it help a lot. And I didn't use lips to create indent because interpreter is in JS. I would need to write interpreter in lips, but it's also example how to use jQuery Terminal. Maybe I move this code to Codepen and create interpreter in Lips in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working indenting based on @coredump link:

```js
function sexp(tokens) {
    var count = 1;
    var i = tokens.length;
    while (count > 0) {
        token = tokens[--i];
        if (!token) {
            return;
        }
        if (token.token === '(') {
            count--;
        } else if (token.token == ')') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return tokens.slice(i);
}
function indent(term, level, offset) {
    var code = term.before_cursor();
    var tokens = lips.tokenize(code, true);
    var last_sexpr = sexp(tokens);
    var lines = code.split('\n');
    var prev_line = lines[lines.length - 1];
    var parse = prev_line.match(/^(\s*)/);
    var spaces = parse[1].length || offset;
    if (last_sexpr) {
        if (last_sexpr[0].line > 0) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        if (last_sexpr.length === 1) {
            return offset + last_sexpr[0].col + 1;
        } else if (['define', 'lambda', 'let'].indexOf(last_sexpr[1].token) !== -1) {
            return offset + last_sexpr[0].col + level;
        } else if (last_sexpr[0].line < last_sexpr[1].line) {
            return offset + last_sexpr[0].col + 1;
        } else if (last_sexpr.length > 3 && last_sexpr[1].line === last_sexpr[3].line) {
            if (last_sexpr[1].token === '(') {
                return offset + last_sexpr[1].col;
            }
            return offset + last_sexpr[3].col;
        } else if (last_sexpr[0].line === last_sexpr[1].line) {
            return offset + last_sexpr[1].col;
        } else {
            var next_tokens = last_sexpr.slice(2);
            for (var i in next_tokens) {
                var token = next_tokens[i];
                if (token.token.trim()) {
                    return token.col;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return spaces + level;
}
```

can be seen on [LIPS homepage](https://jcubic.github.io/lips/).

Answer (score 0):

The standard indentation changes with where the newlines are put. The indentation aligns so that means:

```
(one
 two
 three)

(one two
     three)
```

Yours don't do this. Somehow you are using the two space indentation for the special forms that makes implicit begin.

```
(define
  two)

(define two
  three)
```

Now the rules for when this apply is basically all syntax where you have implicit `begin` like `begin`, `define`, `lambda`, `let` and friends. I think DrRacket does it with every binding starting with "def" abd "begin" such that you can make `def-system-call` and it will actually indent like `define` while `letx` does not.

It could have had some indication in the definition of the extra syntax. Eg. In Common Lisp you can use `&body` instead of `&rest` in macros and they represent the rest of the elements with the distinction that `&body` just indicated it should have a 2 space indentation just like special forms like `defun`. Since you are making your own language you might include something like this in your language :)

Comment: Did you check my current implementation? I've created code based on @coredump link in https://jcubic.github.io/lips/ will add this as an answer, it indent exactly like your 4 examples. (except lambda as special, need to add it to the list of specials).

Comment: @jcubic I only played with the code pen and assumed you updated that when you updated the question.

Comment: I've updated the question and I think also codpen but then @coredump added link with syntax and I've created code based on that syntax and forget to update pen and question.